# Scraping the URL using puppeteer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So take an example: so using puppeteer I gonna scrape the Instagram login page using node.js now my script starts, so the user cred is filled up and then it logs in to the user profile Feed. Now what I need to do is I have to check whether the user logged in or not. what idea I had was to get the current page URL and check whether it is equal to the Instagram's login page. if it is equal then I need to `console.log("this user hasn't logged in yet")`.Else the process flow without error.

```js
if(www.instagram.com == www.instagram.com/personXXX) 
   console.log("user not logged in")
```

Help me out, please...

I'm using **node.js** and **npm puppeteer**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if(page.url() === 'https://www.instagram.com/personXXX' ){
    console.log('User is logged in');
} else{
    console.log('User is not logged in');
}
```

***page.url()*** returns the current browser URL.